# I haven't been prompted for updates in  past 4 days, Why?

Tags: apt, update-manager

I'm running 64 bit version of Ubuntu but I haven't received updates from the repositories since past 4-5 days. Checking the updates manually is taking 5-10 seconds to download the entire repositories whereas previously it used to take 2-3 minutes for the same process.

What's going on? I've got a ton of programs installed since I got my new 1TB hard drive so something should be updated during that period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my side , i can confirm neither did i got any . As far as the size of Apt-get is concerned , it reduces with time , in initial period of release ,efforts are made to provide as stable and secure System possible by updates for Patches , or Bug fixes.

To confirm manually if Packages are up-to date Visit [Precise-Updates packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/). And also you can change your Mirror to assure for same.

Comment: Changing servers actually allowed me to perform a full update to the repos but there were none. That's weird LOL.

Comment: [UbuntuUpdates.org](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/packages/latest_logs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&dist=precise&commit=Go&noppa=0) is another site. I too have not got updates and according to the site I linked, there are none _for me_. (I have a ppa for the Greybird theme and that **is** updating so I don't think anything is broken.)

Comment: Even i thought it was weird , but confirmed it from official sources as above :)